# Why does the setup for my ActiveX .exe hang up when "Setup is updating your system"?

Tags: vb6, windows-8.1, activex

I am currently trying to install my vb6 app on a Windows 8.1 computer via TeamViewer (it's kind of like remote desktop). However, the installation always hangs up after all the files are copied and this message is displayed:

> Setup is updating your system

We've tried it on our own Win8.1Pro desktop (via Remote Desktop this time) and Win2008Server(both via Remote Desktop), and it installed just fine.

Right now, we've narrowed it down to one culprit - **MyProjectInfo.exe** the actual ActiveX .exe. Whether it is me trying to run the .exe for the first time to register it to DCOMCNFG or whether it is the setup.exe running the script $(EXESelfRegister) it just freezes up.

What differences should i look for between 1) our win8.1Pro and win2008server and 2) their win8.1? If it some coding/reference/dependency issue, what could be the cause for why it doesn't error in our desktops?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: People that write installers for a living in general strongly avoid relying on programs to register themselves.  Because, you know, the program could hang and then it is their problem and they have to get a debugger on the machine to find out why it is hanging and who likes to do *that*?  Asking somebody else "why is the program hanging" does not work either.  Of course not.

Comment: So, it's better to register manually by using regserver?

Comment: I think he means to use a proper Windows Installer MSI that can make the registry entries, not a legacy scripted setup.  `Regsvr32.exe` is of no help anyway, since it doesn't do anything but call self-reg entrypoints in DLLs (and renamed DLLs such as OCXs).

Comment: Ah! Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhmm... this is getting embarrassing.

Avast (present in the other person's Win8.1) was blocking MyProjectInfo.exe from running (which is basically what is does with $(EXESelfRegister).

To properly proceed with registering my ActiveEXE program, I had to turn Avast off for a while. And that was that.

This problem may also occur with other anti-virus scanners as well.